# Bash: Randomize text between delimiters

Tags: bash, shell, text, text-processing, text-parsing

How can I identify specific pattern between two outside delimiters '**{**' and '**}**' in text and randomize it inside with delimiter '**;**'

*Examples:*

**Input:**
*I have {red;green;orange} fruit*

**Output:**
*I have green fruit*

**Complicated input:**
*I have {red;green;orange} fruit and cup of {tea;coffee;juice}*

**Output:**
*I have red fruit and cup of tea*

Comment: Extract the text into a variable. Convert it into an array. Select a random element of the array. Replace the delimited text with the selected element.

Comment: Each of those steps should be relatively straightforward, so please make an attempt. If you can't get it to work, show what you tried and explain the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    perl -plE 's!\{(.*?)\}!@x=split/;/,$1;$x[rand@x]!ge' <<<'I have {red;green;orange} fruit and cup of {tea;coffee;juice}'
done
```

produces

```
I have red fruit and cup of coffee
I have red fruit and cup of juice
I have red fruit and cup of juice
I have orange fruit and cup of juice
I have orange fruit and cup of tea
I have red fruit and cup of coffee
I have orange fruit and cup of tea
I have green fruit and cup of tea
I have red fruit and cup of juice
I have green fruit and cup of juice
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way of randomizing the insides of sentances using the variable RANDOM and modulus.

```
rand=$(((RANDOM % 3) + 1))
if [ $rand = 1 ];then
    color="red"
elif [ $rand = 2 ];then
    color="orange"
elif [ $rand = 3 ];then
    color="green"
fi

echo "I have $color fruit."
```

If using the delimiters inside your sentence is absolutely necessary, it would be a bit more interesting, and involve the need for cut, but use the same random number generator used above. An example might look something like this:

```
sent="I have {red;green;orange} fruit"

rand=$(((RANDOM % 3) + 1))

pref="$(echo $sent | cut -f1 -d"{")"
mid="$(echo $sent | cut -f2 -d"{" | cut -f1 -d"}" | cut -f$rand -d";")"
suff="$(echo $sent | cut -f2 -d"}")"

echo "$pref$mid$suff"
```

In this case, if $rand generated as 2, you would get the sentence "I have green fruit." Please ask if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`[g]awk`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html):

```
$ a='I have {red;green;orange} fruit and cup of {tea;coffee;juice}'
$ awk -F '[{}]' '
  BEGIN{ srand() }

  {
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
           if(i%2)
               printf "%s", $i;
           else {
               n=split($i,a,";");
               printf "%s", a[int(rand() * n) + 1];
           }
       print "";
  }' <<< $a
```

Output:

```
I have green fruit and cup of coffee
I have green fruit and cup of tea
```

Pretty simple code, should not need explanation.